# to_char function throws exception with Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm trying to execute sql statement on a grails domain object. Is works fine when executed on db (h2) directly.

```
Call.executeQuery "select to_char(date,'DD') from Call"
```

Via hibernate I get:

> No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
>   -[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
>       +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'to_char' {originalText=to_char}
>       -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
>          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'call0_.date' {propertyName=date,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=date,path={synthetic-alias}.date,tableAlias=call0_,className=com.olamagic.Call,classAlias=null}
>          |  +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}
>          |  -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'date' {originalText=date}
>          -[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''DD''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you executed the SQL statement on H2 directly you were executing H2's SQL. The `GormEntity.executeQuery(String sql)` method executes HQL, not SQL.

HQL doesn't have a `to_char()` function. So getting the equivalent result is more involved:

```
select case when day(date) > 9 then cast(day(date) as text) else concat('0', day(date)) end from Call
```

If you don't mind getting the day as an Integer, then the query simplifies to:

```
select day(date) from Call
```

Comment: what if I need more complex format, let's say dd-mm-yyy. is there anyway to force to execute statement again db rather?

Comment: HQL has functions for day, month, year, etc, but not a date formatting function. You can execute a SQL query with a Hibernate session. Something like this: `Call.withSession { session -> def result = session.createSqlQuery('select...').list() }` You can also use HQL to return the date object as-is and format it in Groovy: `def dates = Call.executeQuery("select date from Call")*.format('dd-mm-yyyy')`. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-exp-functions